# how to get E2E Testing in Protractor results

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I setup some tests in protractor for my angular app and i wanted to run a nightly batch and see next day  some reports of the tests passed or failed .. . I tried without success protractor-html-screenshot-reporter so now i want to see how to save a log . Is this save a log file?
How i could see second day the result of the tests runner ?
My current protractor conf file :

```
exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://imptest2:80/wd/hub',
specs: [
    '../E2E/**/*.spec.js'
    ],

multiCapabilities: [
    {
    'browserName' : 'chrome',
    'ensureCleanSession': 'false',
    'shardTestFiles': 'true',
    maxInstances:8
}
],

params: {
    global: {
        url: 'http://impiis/TestsServices/Client',
        concern: '01'
    }
},
baseUrl: 'http://impiis/TestsServices/Client',

allScriptsTimeout: 500000
};
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a reporter bug it was solved : https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter/pull/38

Answer (score 2):

With this simple protractor config file, you should have protractor-html-screenshot-reporter working

```
var HtmlReporter = require('protractor-html-screenshot-reporter');

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['Exova.LIMS.UI.Testing/e2e/pages/**/*_spec.js'],
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:51494',
    onPrepare: function() {
        // Add a screenshot reporter and store screenshots to `/tmp/screnshots`:
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: 'tmp/screnshots'
        }));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you i will check and let you know , my problems with this was that i had like 50 tests running, some passed some fails , some issued some errors , i used grunt to run them as explained on : http://programmerbuddy.blogspot.ro/2014/03/full-automation-of-protractor-e2e-tests.html and the reports folder (tmp/screnshots your case) got generated / deleted and in the end i use to see only last report or last 2-3 reports but never the all 50 concatenated as i was expected. Did it ever happen to you? Any ideea why? Thanks i'll use your code tomorrow and let you know about

Comment: Same problem .. the screenshot folder get created and then deleted , recreated and so on ..